# Printing out a Vector in "pages" c++

Tags: c++

I have a program that lets user add persons to a file, and also print them out on the console.

This is the function that handles just that, to print out 20 persons at a time. The problem is, it only does it with the first "page" and then prints out all other names on next page. It is probably because when it once hits the IF condition, it never gets out of it.

How do i make the function to reloop and recheck the if condition?

```
void showList(vector<Person> &persons)
{
    showColumns();


    for (auto i = 0; i<persons.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << left << setw(5) << i+1;
        cout << setw(15) << persons[i].nSignature;
        cout << setw(15) << persons[i].fName + " " + persons[i].lName;
        cout << right << setw(3) << fixed << setprecision(2) << persons[i].length << endl;
        if (i > 0 && (i - 1 % 20 == 0)){
            cout << "Press any key to show the next 20 entries..";
            cin.get();
            rensa();
            showColumns();
        }
    }
    cout << endl;

}
```

funktion rensa(); clears the screen.
function showColumns(); shows the name of the columns. (Signature, name, length etc)

Comment: `%` has higher precedence than `-`, so you have `(i - (1 % 20) == 0)`. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Put your parenthesis around `(i - 1) % 20`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your condition to

```
if (i != 0 && (i + 1) % 20 == 0)
```

Because the operator `%` has higher precedence and than `-` and `+`.

And you need i+1, so if yo just printed i = 19, you’ll have (19 +1)%20 == 0, and after the second 20 - i = 39 and (39+1)%20 == 0

Comment: I need to have the "-" because otherwhise the first page prints out 21 names, it jumps over "0", the first entry in the index

Comment: I think you need i+1, so if yo just printed i =19, you’ll have (19 +1)%20, or after the second 20s - (39+1)%20

Comment: Yes, you are right, just thought of that. Feel so dumb! Sorry for taking your time.